# How can I separate the displays and variables in each of my tabs in PyQt?

Tags: python, class, user-interface, pyqt, tabs

I am making a comics viewer but I have a problem.

So I have made a program that opens a new tab every time we click onto "File" and then "test".
When we press on the right and left buttons on the tabs, the value of `self.i` (printed in the console) goes up and down.

However, the problem is that the value of `self.i` changes no matter the tab on which we push the left and right buttons, and the label I want to display `if self.i == 1` only shows onto the last tab opened.

What I need is a way for each tab created to have their own `self.i` and the label to be displayed on any tab depending on their own `self.i` value. I can not figure out how to do this.

Here is the part that opens new tabs when "test" is clicked :

```
def Open(self):
    self.tab = QWidget()
    self.tab.layout = QGridLayout()
    self.nextpagebutton = QPushButton(">", self)
    self.nextpagebutton.setFixedSize(50, 780)
    self.tab.layout.addWidget(self.nextpagebutton, 0, 2)
    self.nextpagebutton.clicked.connect(self.readnext)

    self.prevpagebutton = QPushButton("<", self)
    self.prevpagebutton.setFixedSize(50, 780)
    self.tab.layout.addWidget(self.prevpagebutton, 0, 0)
    self.prevpagebutton.clicked.connect(self.readprev)

    self.n = int(self.n)+1
    self.tabs.addTab(self.tab, "Tab "+str(self.n))
    self.tab.setLayout(self.tab.layout)
```

Here is the part that shows a label when self.i equals to 1 :

```
    def readnext(self):
        self.i+=1
        if self.i == 1:
            self.label = QLabel("testtext")
            self.tab.layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 1)
        print(self.i)

    def readprev(self):
        self.i-=1
        if self.i == 1:
            self.label = QLabel("testtext")
            self.tab.layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 1)
        print(self.i)
```

Here is my full program, you can try it, it works :

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget, QPushButton, QAction, QStatusBar, QToolBar, QTabWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication


class FenetrePrincipale(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Liseuse de Bandes Dessinées")
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 900
        self.height = 850
        self.i = 0

        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.toolbar = QToolBar("Toolbar")
        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setCentralWidget(QWidget(self))
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(self.layout)
        self.move(200, 0)
        self.addToolBar(self.toolbar)

        self.table_widget = MyTableWidget(self)

        self.open = QAction("test", self)
        self.open.triggered.connect(self.table_widget.Open)

        self.setStatusBar(QStatusBar())
        self.menuFichier = self.menuBar().addMenu("&File")
        self.menuFichier.addAction(self.open)

        self.widget=QWidget()
        self.widget.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.table_widget)

        self.show()

class MyTableWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.i = 0
        self.n = 0

        # Initialize tab screen
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.tabs.setDocumentMode(True)
        self.tabs.setMovable(True)

        # Add tabs to widget
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)


    def Open(self):
        self.tab = QWidget()
        self.tab.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.nextpagebutton = QPushButton(">", self)
        self.nextpagebutton.setFixedSize(50, 780)
        self.tab.layout.addWidget(self.nextpagebutton, 0, 2)
        self.nextpagebutton.clicked.connect(self.readnext)

        self.prevpagebutton = QPushButton("<", self)
        self.prevpagebutton.setFixedSize(50, 780)
        self.tab.layout.addWidget(self.prevpagebutton, 0, 0)
        self.prevpagebutton.clicked.connect(self.readprev)

        self.n = int(self.n)+1
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab, "Tab "+str(self.n))
        self.tab.setLayout(self.tab.layout)

    def readnext(self):
        self.i+=1
        if self.i == 1:
            self.label = QLabel("testtext")
            self.tab.layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 1)
        print(self.i)

    def readprev(self):
        self.i-=1
        if self.i == 1:
            self.label = QLabel("testtext")
            self.tab.layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 1)
        print(self.i)



app = QCoreApplication.instance()
if app is None:
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = FenetrePrincipale()
window.show()

app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer !

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget, QPushButton, QAction, QStatusBar, QToolBar, QTabWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication


class FenetrePrincipale(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Liseuse de Bandes Dessinées")
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 900
        self.height = 850
        self.i = 0

        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.toolbar = QToolBar("Toolbar")
        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setCentralWidget(QWidget(self))
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(self.layout)
        self.move(200, 0)
        self.addToolBar(self.toolbar)

        self.table_widget = MyTableWidget(self)

        self.open = QAction("test", self)
        self.open.triggered.connect(self.table_widget.Open)

        self.setStatusBar(QStatusBar())
        self.menuFichier = self.menuBar().addMenu("&File")
        self.menuFichier.addAction(self.open)

        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.widget.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.table_widget)

        self.show()


class MyTableWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.i = {}  # your self.i is now a dict
        self.n = 0
        self.index = {}
        self.tab = {}

        # Initialize tab screen
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.tabs.setDocumentMode(True)
        self.tabs.setMovable(True)

        # Add tabs to widget
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def Open(self):
        n = str(self.n)
        self.i[n] = 0  # assign new key as you make a tab
        self.tab[n] = QWidget()  # differentiate the tabs so we can call it back later when adding label
        self.tab[n].objectName()
        self.tab[n].layout = QGridLayout()
        self.nextpagebutton = QPushButton(">", self)
        self.nextpagebutton.setObjectName('>{}'.format(self.n))  # Give a unique name
        self.nextpagebutton.setFixedSize(50, 780)
        self.tab[n].layout.addWidget(self.nextpagebutton, 0, 2)
        self.nextpagebutton.clicked.connect(self.readnext)

        self.prevpagebutton = QPushButton("<", self)
        self.prevpagebutton.setObjectName('<{}'.format(self.n))  # Give a unique name
        self.prevpagebutton.setFixedSize(50, 780)
        self.tab[n].layout.addWidget(self.prevpagebutton, 0, 0)
        self.prevpagebutton.clicked.connect(self.readprev)

        self.index[n] = self.tabs.addTab(self.tab[n], "Tab " + str(self.n))
        self.tab[n].setLayout(self.tab[n].layout)
        self.n = int(self.n) + 1
        print(self.i)

    def readnext(self):
        name = str(self.sender().objectName())  # get the button's name
        identifier = name[-1]
        self.i[identifier] += 1
        if self.i[identifier] == 1:
            self.label = QLabel("testtext")
            self.tab[identifier].layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 1)
        print(self.i)

    def readprev(self):
        name = str(self.sender().objectName())  # get the button's name
        identifier = name[-1]
        self.i[identifier] -= 1
        if self.i[identifier] == 1:
            self.label = QLabel("testtext")
            self.tab[identifier].layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 1)
        print(self.i)


app = QCoreApplication.instance()
if app is None:
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = FenetrePrincipale()
window.show()

app.exec_()
```